# Is there a way in c++ using nlohmann/json to test json for the presence of key without listing each one separately? And if so, how?

Tags: c++, nlohmann-json

I have an application that is split into a backend and a desktop app. The exchange between them takes place by sending requests in json format and everything functions normally until the backend changes are made concerning the object model itself (for json, a specific key is added or removed).
Here is an example of one of the models (from the desktop app side):

```
void from_json(const nlohmann::json &json, CaseModel &model)
{
    from_json(json, (BasicModel&)model);
    crm::json_extract(model.office, json.at("office"));
    crm::json_extract(model.cid, json.at("cid"));
    crm::json_extract(model.commentary, json.at("commentary"));
    crm::json_extract(model.date_received, json.at("date_received"));
    crm::json_extract(model.purchases, json.at("purchases"));
    crm::json_extract(model.purchases, json.at("payments"));
    crm::json_extract(model.researches, json.at("researches"));
    crm::json_extract(model.participants, json.at("participants"));
    crm::json_extract(model.departments, json.at("related_departments"));
    crm::json_extract(model.experts, json.at("related_experts"));
    crm::json_extract(model.managers, json.at("related_managers"));
    crm::json_extract(model.lawyers, json.at("related_lawyers"));
    crm::json_extract(model.collectors, json.at("related_collectors"));
    crm::json_extract(model.courriers, json.at("related_courriers"));
    crm::json_extract(model.attachments, json.at("attachments"));
    crm::json_extract(model.resolution, json.at("resolution"));
}

void to_json(nlohmann::json &json, const CaseModel &model)
{
    to_json(json, (const BasicModel&)model);
    json["office"] = crm::json_dump(model.office);
    json["cid"] = crm::json_dump(model.cid);
    json["commentary"] = crm::json_dump(model.commentary);
    json["date_received"] = crm::json_dump(model.date_received);
    json["purchases"] = crm::json_dump(model.purchases);
    json["researches"] = crm::json_dump(model.researches);
    json["payments"] = crm::json_dump(model.payments);
    json["participants"] = crm::json_dump(model.participants);
    json["related_departments"] = crm::json_dump(model.departments);
    json["related_experts"] = crm::json_dump(model.experts);
    json["related_managers"] = crm::json_dump(model.managers);
    json["related_lawyers"] = crm::json_dump(model.lawyers);
    json["related_collectors"] = crm::json_dump(model.collectors);
    json["related_courriers"] = crm::json_dump(model.courriers);
    json["attachments"] = crm::json_dump(model.attachments);
    json["resolution"] = crm::json_dump((long int)model.resolution);
}
```

Here's json itself:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "related_departments": [],
      "related_experts": [],
      "related_managers": [],
      "related_lawyers": [],
      "related_courriers": [],
      "related_collectors": [],
      "courtcase": null,
      "contractcase": null,
      "arbitragecase": null,
      "id": 13,
      "resolution": 1,
      "date_sent_lawyer": null,
      "office": 1,
      "cid": "test case cid",
      "commentary": "",
      "date_received": "2021-11-08T12:20:39.337Z",
      "purchases": [],
      "researches": [],
      "participants": [],
      "attachments": [],
      "payments": [
        {
          "pk": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is a unit test:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include <glibmm/datetime.h>
#include <glibmm/ustring.h>

#include "Utility/Concepts.hpp"
#include "Database/Models/CaseModel.hpp"
#include "CaseModel_test.hpp"

template<typename T>
concept HasNeededProperties = requires(T model) {
    typename T::Property;

    T::Property::id;
    Glib::ustring(T::Property::id);

    T::Property::office;
    Glib::ustring(T::Property::office);

    T::Property::cid;
    Glib::ustring(T::Property::cid);

    T::Property::commentary;
    Glib::ustring(T::Property::commentary);

    T::Property::date_received;
    Glib::ustring(T::Property::date_received);

    T::Property::purchases;
    Glib::ustring(T::Property::purchases);

    T::Property::researches;
    Glib::ustring(T::Property::researches);

    T::Property::participants;
    Glib::ustring(T::Property::participants);

    T::Property::departments;
    Glib::ustring(T::Property::departments);

    T::Property::experts;
    Glib::ustring(T::Property::experts);

    T::Property::managers;
    Glib::ustring(T::Property::managers);

    T::Property::lawyers;
    Glib::ustring(T::Property::lawyers);

    T::Property::collectors;
    Glib::ustring(T::Property::collectors);

    T::Property::courriers;
    Glib::ustring(T::Property::courriers);

    T::Property::attachments;
    Glib::ustring(T::Property::attachments);

    T::Property::payments;
    Glib::ustring(T::Property::payments);

    T::Property::resolution;
    Glib::ustring(T::Property::resolution);

    T::Property::date_send_lawyer;
    Glib::ustring(T::Property::date_send_lawyer);
};

TEST(CaseModelConformity, Concept) {
    ASSERT_TRUE(IsDatabaseModel<CaseModel>) << "Doesn't conform to database model description.";
    ASSERT_TRUE(HasModelDbTable<CaseModel>) << "Doesn't have an associated database table.";
    ASSERT_TRUE(HasCaseFields<CaseModel>) << "Doesn't have some required fields.";
}

TEST(CaseModelConformity, Properties) {
    ASSERT_TRUE(HasNeededProperties<CaseModel>) << "Some required properties are missing.";
    EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<Glib::ustring>(CaseModel::Property::id), "id");
    EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<Glib::ustring>(CaseModel::Property::office), "office");
    EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<Glib::ustring>(CaseModel::Property::cid), "cid");
    EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<Glib::ustring>(CaseModel::Property::commentary), "commentary");
    EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<Glib::ustring>(CaseModel::Property::date_received), "date_received");
    EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<Glib::ustring>(CaseModel::Property::purchases), "purchases");
    EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<Glib::ustring>(CaseModel::Property::participants), "participants");
    EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<Glib::ustring>(CaseModel::Property::researches), "researches");
    EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<Glib::ustring>(CaseModel::Property::departments), "related_departments");
    EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<Glib::ustring>(CaseModel::Property::experts), "related_experts");
    EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<Glib::ustring>(CaseModel::Property::managers), "related_managers");
    EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<Glib::ustring>(CaseModel::Property::lawyers), "related_lawyers");
    EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<Glib::ustring>(CaseModel::Property::collectors), "related_collectors");
    EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<Glib::ustring>(CaseModel::Property::courriers), "related_courriers");
    EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<Glib::ustring>(CaseModel::Property::attachments), "attachments");
    EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<Glib::ustring>(CaseModel::Property::payments), "payments");
    EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<Glib::ustring>(CaseModel::Property::resolution), "resolution");
    EXPECT_EQ(static_cast<Glib::ustring>(CaseModel::Property::date_send_lawyer), "date_send_lawyer");
}

TEST(CaseModelConformity, JsonConversion)
{
    ASSERT_TRUE(IsJsonConvertible<CaseModel>);
}
```

There are too many such object models, each has its own json keys and for each registering the key separately to check for availability - not only will kill a lot of time, but it is also pointless, because all of this can be written into working code. But unfortunately, it is not always possible to identify the change and find out where the key mismatch occurred, as a result of which the backend does not accept json.
Ideally, it would be an option to simply compare the two lists of keys with each other, to identify similarities and differences, but I have very little idea of ​​this, and is it even possible to do it?
Does nlohmann have a method for comparing two lists, not listing each element of this list separately, but passing an object?

Comment: An `nlohmann::json` object is just an `std::map<std::string, nlohmann::json>`, so doesn't your answer devolve to finding whether `std::map` has all of the keys in a given set?

Comment: json schema (and validators) are ways to check json.

Comment: https://github.com/pboettch/json-schema-validator